How to do not appear password autofill in chrome and edge through code?
How to do not appear password autofill in chrome and edge through code?
I have tried many times in reference to below site.
Disabling Chrome Autofill
list what I have tried
1. autocomplete = "off" 
2. autocomplete="one-time-code"
3. autocomplete="chrome-off"
4. autocomplete="new-password"

but, none of the solutions worked.
When I focus on the ID input, the autofill does not appear, but when I focus on the password input, the autofill does appear.
How to do not appear password autofill in chrome and edge?
Since the autofill feature is controlled by the browser, I understand that it cannot be disabled through code. I already know that password autofill does not appear through browser settings.  But, I should apply solution through code in my project.
enter image description here

In my case, I was able to solve it with 3 modifications.
First, add “one-time-code” to the autocomplete attribute.
Second, change “type=password” to “type=text”.
Third, add 'text-security:disc' to the css property.
As a result, it doesn't autocomplete in Edge and Chrome.


<form>
  <input type="text" id="id" autocomplete="one-time-code"/>
  <input type="text" id="password"  autocomplete="one-time-code" style="text-security: disc"/>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>



